# How to maintain session on Atheros board using c for access web page

Tags: html, c, ajax, linux

I am using **Atheros development board**. The stack is **LSDK-9.2.0_U10.5.13**. **Linux** version is **mips-linux-2.6.31**. I have **c file, html, js and css files on board**. I have **not** used **cgi** library or **any scripting language** (like php).

Now my problem is, I want to store user session like php into my system using c. Into my system I have opened login.html page first and want to authenticate it using ajax. This part is done, but the problem is how to maintain session using C.

For web access of my development board I want to add login/logout feature. How can I use session into this feature using C language?

Comment: keep session id in cookie, write/read session data to sessions/[ID] file. what you already tried ?

Comment: how to get session id using html only?

Comment: session id it is random string you generate

Comment: ok i got it,how to make session id. but for read/write session data to session/[ID] file, how to achieve this? please give some hint. Thanks

Comment: You mean [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html) ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21679/discussion-between-eicto-and-pkachhia)

Comment: is anybody has answer of my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution of my problem.

I have used jquery.cookie.js and generated cookie using this js and browser sends this cookie along with other headers to server. My C file gets the headers and reads the cookie and stores it . Next time when it will get cookie, it will check the existing cookie. If the cookie is new, it will redirect the user to login page otherwise it will redirect to requested page.

Specially thanks for eicto for his kind help.